# what are the packages with extension (a)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

can anybody explain what are these packages that have extension (.a) that we may add it sometimes to xcode:

1) what exactly are those packages ?

2) how do they differ from other packages that have (.framework) extension ?

3) can I customize/change the code inside the (.a) package ?

thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are a static library (or archive) generated by `ar`. It contains one or more `.o` object files, which contain compiled code and symbols needed for linking.

A `.framework` contains both header files (`.h`) specifying the interface, along with a `.dylib` (a shared library).

A static library is already compiled into machine code - it is not easy to modify code in it. Unlike a shared library, a static library is designed to be linked by the linker - the object code will literally be copied into the destination file, whereas a shared library requires that it is present at runtime since only references are made.

Comment: thank you so much Yann for you answer, I have two questions: 1) what is the (ar) thing you mentioned above, is it a command to generate static libs from Terminal ? 2) giving that the static lib is a machine code, how can i benefit from it when i importing it inside xcode? i mean, I can not read machine code from static lib and thus, I do not know where to use it exactly, where does its real benefit lie ?

Comment: @Ja: 1) yes, though Xcode will invoke it for you when building a static library, 2) You would need to know the interface this library has, often in header files shipped along side the library.

Comment: forgive me Yann I can't vote up because i need more reputation to do so ... thank you so much for your support